# Store PDF or image in SQL Server database with navicat or sql management studio

Tags: sql, image, entity-framework, pdf, navicat

This one's going back to the basics but I haven't been able to find a simple explanation anywhere. I just started working with databases and I'm using a SQL Server database managed mostly with navicat (but I have SQL Server Management Studio as well) and I need to store a PDF or image in the database.

I'm using Entity Framework to interface the database with the C# app I am building. A simple explanation assuming little knowledge of database management would be much appreciated.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The database size will grow exponentially if you start storing images and PDF's.

A better approach would probably be to store the path of the file in the database and then load the item by referencing the proper path.

**EDIT:**
It's going to depend on the file structure of your application really.  A simple version of retrieving a PDF could be the following:

Example Path:
    /PDF/username.PDF

You store the path of the PDF in the DB, maybe under pdfPath.  Then when you retrieve the path from the database direct the user to the correct link using the path you got from the query.

Comment: What are you using to present your data, PHP, Coldfusion, Ruby?

Comment: That doesn't make it any less accurate.  I'd rather give someone a heads up on a better design option instead of having it become a problem for them later on.